# Using dustjs how do I show a block of code when an array's size is greater than one

Tags: dust.js

I am using dust 1.1.1.  I've tried nesting the @size help inside of an @if but that broke.

Another trick to it is once I've determined the length is greater than one I then want to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dust grammar](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/src/dust.pegjs) does not allow a helper to be used inside another helper, except in the body.

Instead, I would try something like this:

```
{#myArray}
  {@gt key=$len value=1}{.}{/gt}
{/myArray}
```

This will only output the value of the element in the array if the length of the array (`$len`) is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this was:

```
{?myArray[1]}
    {!Do greater than one stuff!}
{/myArray[1]}
```