# How can I have a condition on the length of an array in Dust?

Tags: dust.js

Basically I want to be able to say if the number of items is more than 1 do something, else do something else.

Here is the sample json data:

```
  "items": [
    { "key1" : "val1" }, 
    { "key2" : "val2" }
    ]
```

I can get the size of elements by using: 
`{@size key=items}{.}{/size}`
But the problem is where I want to put this inside the if condition similar to:

`{@if cond="1 < '{@size key='items' /}'"}
    Size was bigger than 1
{/if}`

(which gives me a syntax error). Unfortunately the documentation doesn't get into the details and is of very little help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using dustjs how do I show a block of code when an array's size is greater than one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220800/using-dustjs-how-do-i-show-a-block-of-code-when-an-arrays-size-is-greater-than)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the length of an array using `arrayName.length`, and you can use the greater than (`@gt`), less than (`@lt`), greater than or equal to (`@gte`), less than or equal to (`@lte`), or equals (`@eq`) helpers to do the comparison. The example below shows how to check if the length of an array is greater than 3.

```
{@gt key=items.length value=3}There are more than 3 items{/gt}
```

Where the data would look something like:

```
{
  items: [
    {name: 'a'},
    {name: 'b'},
    {name: 'c'},
    {name: 'dee'}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I want to display a section only if there is something there:
I have a collection List in product.hours

```
{@gt key=product.hours.length value=0}
my stuff goes here
{/gt}
```